# Potential of cells in series

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries

If two cells are connected in series, say,

[image: cells]

I understand that charge from cell 1 have a potential of 10 V would increase it's potential by 5V on moving through the second cell (neglecting internal resistance).

But since both are cells, doesn't the 5V cell have the capability to produce charge as well? The charge coming from that cell should only have a potential of 5V

I know this theory is definitely wrong but I want to know why. I think it's because of the way the cells are connected but I'm sure. In any case, even if I'm right, please elaborate.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My mistake. I'll edit the question.

Comment: That charge that went through *only* the 5 V cell started at a potential of 10 V.   So its final potential is 15 V.    (I'm assuming here that 0 V is at the far left of your diagram, and the polarity of the cells is positive to the right.  Conventionally, the longer line is the positive side of the cell.)  Am I not understanding the question?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine connecting these two cells into a circuit, with some other components.  Electrons will move through the wires of the circuit.  When the electrons reach the positive terminal of a cell, new electrons with more energy will appear at the negative terminal of the same cell.  This happens at *both* cells.

Each electron entering the 10V cell is replaced in the circuit by an electron with 10eV more energy; and each electron entering the 5V cell is replaced by an electron with 5eV more energy.  All these electrons are indistinguishable from one another, except for the energy that they carry.  And therefore, the overall effect is equivalent to a single cell where each electron is replaced by an electron with 15eV more energy - that is, a 15V cell.

Those 15eV of energy will then be used up by whatever additional components are in the circuit, including the internal resistances of both cells.

Comment: This would be perfect for current passing in loops after the initial loop. In the initial loop, the charges present in the conducting wire after the 10V cell only pass through the 5V cell don't they? So in the initial loop wouldn't 1C of charge have only 5J of expendable energy?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "initial loop".  I'm visualising a circuit where you have these two cells plus a light bulb or something similar.  All the charges involved travel through all three components.

Comment: Say you add a switch to the circuit. The initial loop is when the circuit is closed and charges move through one loop of the circuit and return back to their original position. In that loop, charges initially located in front of the 10V cell would only pass through the 5V cell

Comment: perfect explanation, well done!!

Comment: This explanation makes me uneasy. For example in *"The charges would all still have to go through both cells to get back to their starting position."* contradicts the idea that the charges never return to their starting position because, in  a primary cell, the negative charges (which travel through the metal wires of a typical circuit) are produced at an anode and permanently consumed at the cathode and never reach the anode ever again. The circuit is completed by totally different and separate positive charges flowing in the opposite direction.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I see what you mean.  I am guilty of playing fast-and-loose with the word "charge".  I think I need to re-word this to clarify that when current moves through a dry cell, the electrons are chemically absorbed at one end, and new electrons chemically produced at the other.   If I can't work out a better way of wording what I've written, I shall delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you, @RedGrittyBrick, for your help with this answer.  I think it's better now.  I now see that talking about a "charge moving through a cell" is kind of ambiguous; and I certainly didn't want to paint a false impression of electrons passing all the way through a cell.  If you think my answer is still inadequate, I'd really appreciate it if you could comment again, and I will delete it.  Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Again I understand this answer perfectly, even better than before thanks to @RedGrittyBrick and DavidWallace 's improved answer. But I still have the same doubt. If you had a switch in the circuit, and closed it, the initial loop would be when first couple of electrons produced at the negative electrode of the 5V cell reached the positive of the 10V. However, in this loop, there is a conducting wire (having electrons) between the two cells. The electrons in this wire, only reach the positive electrode of the 5V cell. Sorry if I seem extremely ignorant, I just want to clarify this.

Comment: I don't follow.  The voltage of a cell measures the _difference_ in the energy of the electrons at each end of the cell; not the total amount of energy of the electrons at the negative terminal.